# bootstrap example for spans does not show correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have installed bootstrap and followed the get started directions. I created some buttons and they work. But any of the span instructions do not work. It seems to be ignored by the browsers.

I tried the fiddle at .../MgcDU/3107/ as a double-check and lo and behold, the spans don't show up right for me. All divs span the entire screen width and are flushed to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is not pointing to the correct 'bootstrap.css' location.

Use Bootply instead: http://bootply.com/86845 (this includes Bootstrap)

Or, you can reference the appropriate Bootstrap version on Bootstrap CDN: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to copy the code I was working on my machine and it works. So, I a bit puzzled...I must not be pointing to the right bootstrap.css in my setup as well, although I have checked several times. I just downloaded version 3.0.0 from the site.

Comment: If you're using 3.0.0, the class names are different (ie: 'col-md-3' instead of 'span3') - see here for more info: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you very much!